# SQL запрос UNION с добавлением колонки

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Есть SQL запрос:

К первой таблице:

```
SELECT DISTINCT LEFT(Prefix,3) AS `Prefix`, group_concat(distinct `Primary City` separator ', ') AS `Citys` FROM phonelist WHERE State = 'washington' GROUP BY LEFT(Prefix,3)
```

Выдает:

```
Prefix | Citys
--------------
206    | Seattle WA, Richmond Beach WA
360    | Longview WA, Lynden WA, Port Angeles WA
425    | Seattle WA, Renton WA, Everett WA, Bellevue WA
509    | Walla Walla WA, Ellensburg WA, Spokane WA
```

Ко второй таблице:

```
SELECT LEFT(Prefix,3), group_concat(distinct `Zip` separator ', ') AS `Zip` FROM Zip where Prefix LIKE '509%'
```

Выдает:

```
Prefix | Zip
--------------
509    | 98926, 99336, 99338, 99337, 98930, 99362
```

Как объединить их так, чтобы в качестве *Prefix LIKE '509%'* вместо *509* использовался *Prefix* из первой колонки первого запроса, а полученная колонка *Zip* добавлялась к итоговой таблице

Итоговый вывод:

```
Prefix | Citys | Zip 
--------------------------------------------------------
206    | Seattle WA, Richmond Beach WA | 9898, 8787, 8787, 8787,
360    | Longview WA, Lynden WA, Port Angeles WA | 8787, 8787, 8787, 8787,
425    | Seattle WA, Renton WA, Everett WA, Bellevue WA | 44654, 67868, 6876
509    | Walla Walla WA, Ellensburg WA, Spokane WA | 98926, 99336, 99338, 99337, 98930, 99362
```

Такое вообще возможно?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно, как то так:

```
SELECT LEFT(Prefix,3) AS `Prefix`, group_concat(distinct `Primary City` separator ', ') AS `Citys`,
       (SELECT group_concat(distinct `Zip` separator ', ')
          FROM Zip Z
         where Z.Prefix LIKE concat(LEFT(P.Prefix,3),'%')
       ) `Zip`
  FROM phonelist P
 WHERE State = 'washington'
 GROUP BY LEFT(Prefix,3)
```

И что то мне подсказывает, что distinct в данном запросе не нужен.